# Sizing Content to Fill `Client Area` of Window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I am having trouble sizing a WPF control (I'll use the `Grid` control in this example) to the size of the `Client` area of a `Window`. I realize that the `Grid` automatically fills all available space by default, however I require the `Grid`'s `Width` to be set manually so that I may bind to it from another control (a DataGrid with one of its column's `Width`'s set to `Star` if it makes any difference).

Please consider the following XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TestApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="768" Width="1024"
        x:Name="mainWindow">

    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Grid x:Name="testGrid" Background="DarkGray">
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>

</Window>
```

And the following Code-Behind:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace TestApplication
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            testGrid.Width = mainWindow.Width - (SystemParameters.BorderWidth * 2);
        }
    }
}
```

When running this simple application, the `Grid` has a width that is slightly larger than the `Client` area of the `Window`, resulting in a `Horizontal Scroll Bar` being displayed. If `SystemParameters.BorderWidth` does not accurately calculate the width of the `Window`'s border, what does?

As per the most recent MSDN documentation, `SystemParameters.BorderWidth`: *Gets the metric that determines the border width of the nonclient area of a nonminimized window.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having fought with this sizing issue for quite some time, I have finally found an elegant solution to the problem. Though I have alread selected @Rick Sladkey's response as the answer (and answer my question it did), I thought I might post my updated understanding in hopes that it might help someone else down the line.

The real frustration point, it turns out, was in dealing with the `ScrollViewer`. While sizing my content to the `ActualWidth` of the `ScrollViewer` worked wonderfully when it's `VerticalScrollBar` was not visible, things began to break down as soon as my content grew to a vertically scrollable height. Though I had expected the binding on `ActualWidth` to resize my contol to fit within the viewable area of the `ScrollViewer`, in reality it remained the same width and became horizontally scrollable as well.

As it turns out, the fix was actually quite simple. Rather than binding the height or width of a control to the `ActualHeight` or `ActualWidth` of the `ScrollViewer` (respectively), bind the height or width of the control to the `ViewportHeight` or `ViewportWidth` of the `ScrollViewer`.

Comment: +1, as it helps for `ScrollViewer`; unfortunately, [`ViewportWidth`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollcontentpresenter.viewportwidth%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`ViewportHeight`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollcontentpresenter.viewportheight%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) do not seem to be dependency properties on [`ScrollContentPresenter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollcontentpresenter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

Here is one way of binding the size of the client width with no code-behind:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Grid x:Name="testGrid" Background="DarkGray" Width="{Binding Content.ActualWidth, ElementName=mainWindow}">
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

This uses your named top-level `Window` and gets with actual width of it's content, a `ScrollViewer` in this case.  If for some reason you want to want the content of the window to be a different size than the window you can enclose it in an empty `Grid` so this technique still works.

Comment: This is exactly the functionality that I am looking for. Now I just need to find a way to deal with Margins.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of setting the width manually, how about binding to the grid's `ActualWidth` property instead (this will give you an actual value)

Comment: That won't work for what I am trying to accomplish. The `Grid`, I've found, dynamically expands to fit its contained elements. I am actually trying to ensure that the elements within the `Grid` grow no larger than the `Grid`. For example, if a `DataGridTextColumn` has it's Width set to Star, it will cause the Containing `Grid` to grow as well.